# Finding solutions for a 2 variable function

Tags: algorithm, search, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I have a function Y = f(a,b).

a and b are bounded by 0

The function is not defined, but it can be imagined like a black box where if I plug in the values of (a,b), I get a 'Y'. Also there could be other values of (a,b) which give the same Y. But it will always be a finite number of (a,b).

I used a brute search and found all the values and used it to plot a 3 D graph, which is shown below. But this is not the curve always. This is just for one case of my initial conditions.

Now my objective is that knowing a specific value of Y', I need to find all the solutions (a,b) with minimum number of iterations. (By Iteration I mean, plugging (a,b) into the function to get Y).

[image: (Eta, T) = (a,b)]

Comment: Which programming language and software package are you using to plot the graph?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I'm using C++ and Visual Basic. The plot was basically made after taking all the values using a brute algorithm in Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case there's no solution. If f is some hash function the only solution is to try all inputs.

Now assuming that f is continuous, at least around the value you are looking for and that it's relatively smooth, then you can take a triangle covering the area where you are looking for values, compute it for the vertices and for the center of the triangle and guess which of the 3 triangles likely holds your solution and then restrict to that one.

Alternatively you can create a grid over the area, compute the values at every vertex in the grid and then restrict the search to the cells where you think the value might be and continue there. This way you can make sure that the cells are sufficiently small so that you don't miss features of interest.

This all relies on having some idea of how f behaves, and works in a bad way or doesn't work at all if f doesn't match you expectation.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to use a Taylor series curve fitting to approximate the plot in a few iterations and then use a brute search around that area to find the value.